# Performance of navigator.clipboard.write vs event.clipboardData.setData

Tags: javascript, performance, clipboard

In testing out the following two copy-to-clipboard actions:

```
event.clipboardData.setData('text/html', html);
```

And:

```
navigator.clipboard.write(new ClipboardItem({"text/html": new Blob([html], {type: "text/html"})
```

The first method is literally about 100x faster when trying to copy the same data. Is there a reason why one is so much faster than the other? Is there any way to achieve closer-to-parity between them?

References for both found [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/).

Comment: One is synchronous the other isn't. Why does it matter the async one takes a long time? It shouldn't block your page.

Comment: @Kaiido it's for a copy-paste. If someone wants to copy data into another application, say excel -- the common user action is to press cmd-c, and then in the other application cmd-p. If the user has to wait 50 seconds to do that, who cares if the operation is sync or async? What if, for example, every time I pasted in code into StackOverflow it took 30s to paste in -- sure, if it's async I could 'add more text' but the end result is still the user has to wait 30s for what they expect to happen to actually happen.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249, good point. What was the size of data you were actually copying? What browser(s) were you using? I think each have their use depending on the need. If it's taking 30 seconds to copy data, your browser tab, and potentially the browser itself could be blocked with the sync method. With async, you could display a progress bar with a friendly message while you continue doing other things on the web app. You could also set a time-out. That performance difference is very interesting though.